How to retrieve the schema version of LDAP server with ldapsearch?
Is it possible to retrieve such a property by querying, say, the Root DSE or the schema? I read that the objectVersion property has this information (see https://blog.netwrix.com/2023/04/06/get-adobject-cmdlet-in-powershell/), but I am unable to access it using a client such as ldapsearch.
I attempted to query my local LDAP server Root DSE and Schema for the objectVersion attribute, but discovered that it is not an attribute, but rather a property.
Any ideas?
Thank you!

Is this about AD specifically? LDAP does not have "schema version" as a general term.

that's good point that I haven't specified in the original question. But how to retrieve such property without using AD specific tools (like in the link I shared) but ldapsearch instead?
